# Example columns for a non-clustered index

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

What are the good example columns for which I should never create an index? As per my understanding the clustered index should often be done on primary keys (default) as it represents base data as a whole. But on which columns I should never create a non-clustered index?

Comment: It is not correct that the clustered index should only be the primary key.  The optimal choice for the clustered index depends on how the table is queried, which is often but not always the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot say for sure. The fact is: you **cannot** create an index on any column (or combination of columns) that has a max size of more than 900 bytes - so any columns like `VARCHAR(1000)` or `VARCHAR(MAX)` **cannot** be indexed.

Other than that - it reallly **depends** on what your system does! There's no *magic rule* what columns to index - or which to avoid.

In general: fewer indexes are better than too many. Most DB developers tend to over-index their databases - but as I said - this is really heavily dependent on the exact situation of your system - there's no simple, general rules to follow here.

Comment: Hey marc_s thanks for the response..Is gender / date/customer_name  good candidate for clustering ?If yes/no then why?

Comment: What **datatypes** are those columns? Typically, a **compound** index (made up from multiple columns), and one containing a **variable length** column (like `customer_name` most likely is) are **not ideal** for a clustering index

Comment: Gender is char type and date is Date type.Is it mean we choose column based on data type ? Actually this question was asked in interview ..what columns (gender / date / customer Id / customer name) are not good as candidate to indexed on  ?

Comment: @user2895589: the most important point is: **HOW LONG** is your clustering key in total, how many bytes? And also: does it include non-unique values, does it include `NULL`, does it include variable length (`varchar`) values? Those are all bad fits for a clustered index

Comment: @user2895589: read Kimberly Tripp's blog post [Ever-increasing clustering key – the Clustered Index Debate……….again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-again/) - she explains very well and in great detail what a **well chosen** clustering key is and should be!

Comment: @user2895589, I think the answer to the interview guestion is gender, because it is likely not selective enough to be useful.  But I suspect the question was dumbed down to assume single-column indexes.

Comment: Found one more similar post https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/effective-clustered-indexes/